# Getting errors trying to run git commands

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell

I get these errors in my python script. It is designed to create a repo and then push the first commit with a readme file. It does not and gives me 3 errors instead.

```
Initialized empty Git repository in D:/Project/Repos/autoRepo/.git/
error: pathspec 'commit'' did not match any file(s) known to git
error: src refspec 'main' does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'origin'
```

```
from github import *
from secure import GITHUB_TOKEN
import argparse
import os

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--name", "-n", type=str, dest="name", required=True)
parser.add_argument("--private", "-p", dest="is_private", action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args()
repo_name = args.name 
is_private = args.is_private
g = Github(GITHUB_TOKEN)  # safer alternative, if you have an access token

try:
    u = g.get_user()
    repo = u.create_repo(repo_name, private=is_private)
    REPO_PATH="D:\Project\Repos\\"
    os.chdir (REPO_PATH)
    os.system(f"git init {repo_name}")
    os.chdir(os.path.join(REPO_PATH, repo_name))
    os.system(f"git remote add origin git@github.com:TallKid420/{repo_name}.git")
    with open('README.md', 'w') as fd:
        print(f'# {repo_name}', file=fd)
    os.system("git add README.md")
    os.system("git commit -m 'first commit'")
    os.system("git branch -M 'main'")
    os.system("git push -u origin main")
except FileExistsError as err:
    raise SystemExit(err)
```

I run it with this line in terminal
`python d:/SCripts/SetupGitProject.py --name autoRepo -p`

Comment: I have updated the title and removed the github tags from this question because it has nothing to do with the github api: your errors are all coming from running `git` commands locally.

Answer (score 1):

First, this doesn't make any sense:

```
os.system("mkdir " + repo_name)
os.chdir(REPO_PATH + repo_name)
os.system("git remote add origin git@github.com:TallKid420/"+repo_name+".git")
os.system("echo '# "+repo_name+"e' >> README.md")
os.system("git init")
```

First, you can't `git remote add` in an empty directory; you need to initialize a git repository first. You should be seeing the error:

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
```

Second, there's no reason to create the empty directory like this; `git init` will do that for you.  So the above should become:

```
os.system(f"git init {repo_name}")
os.chdir(os.path.join(REPO_PATH, repo_name))
os.system(f"git remote add origin git@github.com:TallKid420/{repo_name}.git")
```

Then the remainder of your script becomes:

```
os.system(f"echo '# {repo_name}' >> README.md")
os.system("git add README.md")
os.system("git commit -m 'first commit'")
os.system("git branch -M 'main'")
os.system("git push -u origin main")
```

On my system, this runs without errors and successfully pushes to the
remote repository. However, there are a number of things I would
change about this script:

1. Use `subprocess` instead of `os.system`. You don't need to invoke
   the shell for all of these tasks:

   ```
   subprocess.check_call(['git', 'commit', '-m', 'first commit'])
   ```

   Etc.
2. If you need to write text content to a file, just use Python.

   ```
   with open('README.md', 'w') as fd:
       print(f'# {repo_name}', file=fd)
   ```
3. Rather than creating the remote repository, trying to create the
   local directory, then deleting the remote repository if the
   directory already exists locally...why not just check if the
   directory exists first, and just exit at that point?

Comment: I updated the script but it still gave me errors I updated the post

Comment: There appear to be some idiosyncrasies with `os.system` on Windows and how quoted strings are handled. If you use `subprocess` as I suggested the problem goes away.